# Why is negative specific exception expectation deprecated in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, deprecated

Seems like I am permitted to specify exception class for `.to` but not for `.not_to`?
What are exact reasons of this?

```
 Failure/Error: expect{ smth }.not_to raise_exception SomeExceptionClass
 ArgumentError:
   `expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass)` is not valid, use `expect { }.not_to raise_error` (with no args) instead
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Nakilon's answer a little:

This is a design decision on their part.  It would appear that they think this is not a good test to specify, because if you expect that a certain error *not* be raised, then the test will pass if:

- no error is raised
- some other error is raised

...which is at least, imprecise. Probably your code only wants to do one of these things.

That appears to be the reasoning, anyway -- I wouldn't like to say how fair it was.

Comment: Excellent summary of the discussion at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/231. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [changelog](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/854092d34fa28dabf2bdc9e45118107cae413392/Changelog.md#300beta1--2013-11-07):

> Make `expect { }.to_not raise_error(SomeSpecificClass, message)`, `expect { }.to_not raise_error(SomeSpecificClass)` and `expect { }.to_not raise_error(message)` invalid, since they are prone to hiding failures.
>   Instead, use `expect { }.to_not raise_error` (with no args). (Sam
>   Phippen)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they realised that there was no reason to deprecate the exception class parameter, so it currently works: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-5/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

For example, in Selenium, after checking for some condition to become true:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(
  message: message,
  timeout: timeout,
).until do
  f() == x
end
```

it's now easy to also wait that it does not become false in next seconds by negating the timeout exception:

```
  begin
    Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(
      timeout: timeout,
    ).until do
      f() != x
    end
    raise message
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError
  end
```